# Difference between post, upsert and update in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, upsert

How to make upsert to update based on a single paramter in Elastic serach.

```
POST questiondetails_back/question_back/_update
    {
    "doc":{

       "question_id": 1111112555,
       "user": "Induee"
    },
    "upsert":true

}
```

The above query updates if it finds the same question id or user .

But how do i make it see for only questionid and update the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID should be in the URL otherwise it won't work:

```
                               the id must be specified here
                                            |
                                            v
POST questiondetails_back/question_back/1111112555/_update
{
    "doc": {
       "user": "Induee"
    },
    "doc_as_upsert": true
}
```

Comment: This is what i am getting if i use this.

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "not_x_content_exception",
      "reason": "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: which version of ES are you using?

Comment: also note that `upsert` should actually be `doc_as_upsert`, that's probably the reason

Comment: elastic search version 6.2

Comment: Ok, see my earlier comment

Comment: POST questiondetails_back/question_back/1111112555/_update/
    {
    "doc":{
       "user": "Indueeeee"
    },
    "doc_as_upsert":true
    
}


Is this how you are saying ?

Comment: Thankyou so much for your response.
If i use the way you say,it is considering the _id which is the elastic search default id.
Here I want it our query to update the record based on other attribute present in the data which is question id . 
I want the query to search with question id and update it. Is this possible by any chance using upsert??

Comment: Ok, I see now, what you're actually asking is for the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html), however, that API doesn't support upserting, it will only update all documents that match the query. So basically you want to update all documents that match `question_id: 1111112555` with `user: Induee` and if no documents exists, then you want to create one... updating by query and upserting are actually two different things

Comment: oK..for this scenario.. Should i use update instead of upsert?

Comment: What i am actually looking for is.... I need to insert the record if there is no record present with the question id and update the whole record if there is a record present with that question id.

Comment: can there only be a single document with that question id?

Comment: Then you should use the `questionId` field as the document `_id` and use the solution is showed above.

Comment: Infact i tried this way...

POST questiondetails_back/question_back/111111255566/_update/
    {
    "doc":{
       "user": "India"
    }
}

This solved my query

Comment: This has a concern actually.... This is not replacing the whole document.. Its just adding the extra parameters

Comment: How wil i make this query to replace the document.

POST questiondetails_back/question_back/1111112555/_update
{
    "doc": {
       "user": "Induee"
    },
    "doc_as_upsert": true
}

Comment: Then you're not looking for an update but just a reindexing of the document. Simply use the endpoint `PUT questiondetails_back/question_back/1111112555/`and send the doc in the request body